# How to prepare json document for nth level (parent child) select drop down list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I want to prepare a json format document using jQuery for select drop down list to nth level.

I have drop down list like multidimensional array.

So when you click on plus button, it's create parent child relationship of nth level.
So, basically i want to select index and their value.

Example json document on change or click like below.

```js
var json = {
  "0": {
    "0": "1",
    "0": {
      "0": "1",
      "1": { "2": {
        "0": "1"}
      },
      "3": "4",
    },
    "1": {
      "0": "1",
      "1": "2",
      "3": "4",
    },
    "3": {
      "0": "1",
      "2": "2",
      "4": "4",
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  generateSelectBox = function() {
    var html = "<select>";
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      html += '<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';
    }
    html += "<select>";
    return html;
  }
  var generateHtml = function() {
    return '<div class="common"> <span>Keypress</span> ' +
      generateSelectBox() + ' <span class="common_level">Plus</span> </div>'
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".common_level", function() {
    var html = generateHtml();
    $(this).parents(".common").first().append(html)
  });
});
// Below jQuery code not working as per my requirement.

$(document).on("click", ".common_level", function() {
  var value = $("div select:nth-child(0)").val();
  //var value = $("select").eq(15).val();
  console.log(value);
});

$(document).on("change", ".common_level", function() {
  var value = $("div select:nth-child(0)").val();
  //var value = $("select").eq(15).val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="common">
  <span class="common_level">Plus</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Why not changing (in the part of the code that doesn't work) `$(document).on("change", ".common_level", function () {` to something like `$(".common_level").on("change", "select", function () { console.log( this.value ); });`

Comment: @AlonEitan because he needs to delegate

Comment: @mplungjan Oh right, so maybe `$(document).on("change", ".common select", function () { console.log( this.value ); });` (But as you said, a working example will allow us to debug it better)

Comment: @Amit:  I fixed invalid object `"1": { "2": {
        "0": "1"}` and add (0) to the nth-child selector - can you fix any other issues? - you are not actually using your JSObject now

Comment: @mplungjan i am getting undefined, when clicked on plus text. can you please check once.

Comment: @mplungjan Actually i have  to push the element in an array, while clicked or on change, then after encode the array in json format. this drop down section is in a form and on form submission, get the value of all selected parent child.